# probability of T total eyes when throwing N dice with S sides

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, probability, dice

I want to calculate the probability of the event that the sum of all eyes of `n` dice with `s` sides (numbered from 1 to `s`) is equal to `t`. My language is Python 3.

My current approach is pretty much a try-and-count solution and only works for small numbers (running `probability(10, 10, 50)` already ate all my RAM and forced me to hard reset):

```
import itertools
def probability(n, s, t):
    all_rolls=list(itertools.product(range(1,s+1), repeat=n))
    target_rolls=[l for l in all_rolls if sum(l)==t]
    return round(len(target_rolls)/len(all_rolls), 4)
```

But I honestly don't know how else to solve this. Can you please help me to get on the right track?

Comment: I assume you mean `t` instead of `x`?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes, you're right, I edited the question to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off: the total possible roll combinations will always be `s**n`, so you don't need to store a list of all possibilities in order to get it's length.  Similarly you can just keep a running total of desired outcomes instead of keeping a list of them to save on memory space but it still won't speed up the function a whole lot:

```
def probability(n, s, t):
    all_rolls = itertools.product(range(1,s+1), repeat=n) #no list, leave it a generator
    target_rolls=sum(1 for l in all_rolls if sum(l)==t) #just total them up
    return round(target_rolls/s**n, 4)
```

A much more efficient way of calculating the possibilities is with a `dict` and some clever iteration. Each dictionary will use the roll value as keys and frequency as value, each iteration the `prev` will be this dict for the previous X dice and `cur` will be updated from it with the addition of another die:

```
import collections
def probability(n, s, t):
    prev = {0:1} #previous roll is 0 for first time
    for _ in range(n):
        cur = collections.defaultdict(int) #current probability
        for r,times in prev.items():
            for i in range(1,s+1):
                #if r occured `times` times in the last iteration then
                #r+i have `times` more possibilities for the current iteration.
                cur[r+i]+=times
        prev = cur #use this for the next iteration

    return cur[t] / s**n
    #return round(cur[t] / s**n , 4)
```

note 1: since `cur` is a defaultdict trying to look up a number that is not not possible with the given input will return 0

note 2: since this method puts together a dictionary with all possible outcomes you can return `cur` and do the calculation for multiple different possible outcomes on the same dice rolls.

Comment: Very nice and fast solution, although I don't fully understand why it works yet... Thank you!

Comment: I found this [wikihow - method2: recursion](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Multiple-Dice-Probabilities) after making the function, it demonstrates the same process in a spreadsheet. May help you understand how it works.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

itertools.product is too slow for big number of sides > 5 and number of sides > 6. On my machine having dice_number: 10 and sides: 10 took one and a half hours to calculate.
Instead I used [numpy.polypow](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polypow.html) function to calculate targets and it took less than a second to calculate.

```
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polypow

def probability(dice_number, sides, target):
    """
    Using numpy polynomial
    The number of ways to obtain x as a sum of n s-sided dice
    is given by the coefficients of the polynomial:

    f(x) = (x + x^2 + ... + x^s)^n
    """

    # power series (note that the power series starts from x^1, therefore
    # the first coefficient is zero)
    powers = [0] + [1] * sides
    # f(x) polynomial, computed used polypow in numpy
    poly = polypow(powers, dice_number)
    return poly[target] / sides ** dice_number if target < len(poly) else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop making lists.  Just use lazy evaluation.

```
from itertools import product

def prob(dice, pips, target):
    rolls = product(range(1, pips+1), repeat=dice)
    targets = sum(1 for roll in rolls if sum(roll) == target)
    return targets / pips**dice
```

Tests:

```
for i in range(5, 26):
    print(i, prob(5, 5, i))
print('sum: ', sum(prob(5, 5, i) for i in range(5, 26)))
# prints
5 0.00032
6 0.0016
7 0.0048
8 0.0112
9 0.0224
10 0.03872
11 0.0592
12 0.0816
13 0.1024
14 0.1168
15 0.12192  # symmetrical, with peak in middle
16 0.1168
17 0.1024
18 0.0816
19 0.0592
20 0.03872
21 0.0224
22 0.0112
23 0.0048
24 0.0016
25 0.00032
sum:  1.0000000000000002
```

edit: removed unused def

Comment: you don't use `tsum` inner function?

Comment: Whoops.  I was going to, but decided `if` in generator expression would be faster.  Removed.

Comment: prob(8, 8, 40) took about 3 seconds.  I leave running prob(10, 10, 50) to you.  Probabilities could be calculated much faster by formulas rather than brute-force enumeration, but I presume that the answer is not the point of the exercise.

Comment: Your improvement is nice as I can now run the function for big numbers without crashing my machine because of a memory overflow, but it still takes forever to calculate big numbers. Therefore I'm accepting the other answer.